# Is there any Webhook for Reddit to catch messages?

Tags: webhooks, reddit

I'm creating a platform to manage reddit messages. I need to catch the messages as soon as they are posted and to answer back. How can I receive a message as soon as it is posted, and how I can answer back with a PM to the sender?

Answer (score 0):

No, there's simply no webhooks provided by Reddit.

Instead, you need to poll the API instead. You can use the JSON, RSS, or XML API in order to get information from Reddit's API.

You can use [`/api/comment`](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api#POST_api_comment) to reply to a message.